# Pass a Javascript value to Apex Application item

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex

How to pass the value of retVal variable from this JS function to an application item, so I could store the value in the DB?
This function open a prompt to enter the value.

```
function getEmailValue() {
           var retVal = prompt("Enter your Email Address : ", "your Email here");
           document.write("An Email will be send to : " + retVal );
        }
```

Note:

1. This JS function runs from a JS file exists in Static Application
   Files it calls Ajax callback from APEX side.
2. P12_PAUSE_EMAIL is an application item.
3. I can't use page items or Dynamic actions as there is no actual page.

I tried **apex.item** , **$v** and **$** , but it gives undefined object.

Comment: What is the end goal you are trying to achieve? What version of APEX are you using?

Comment: I want to store the input value to the DB through JS dialog , I'm using version 21.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on using a prompt for this.

If you want a similar UI, you could simply use an inline dialog or a modal dialog page (have a look at the [Universal Theme Sample Application](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/apex_pm/r/ut/inline-dialog) for examples.

In either of these, you could have an item which you could then use directly (granted it's listed in the items to submit to your ajax callback [see the pageItems attribute here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/21.2/aexjs/apex.server.html#.process) ).

Comment: This is seems to be a good idea , but how can I open a APEX dialog page from a native JS code ?

Comment: Why does the modal page need to be launched from native JS code? You should create a button or link that opens the modal on your current page.

Comment: I totally agree with you but this is how the system built and I have to do this kind of enhancements.

Comment: you could use a DA with an open region action on clikc of a button as @BODYBOND said, you could also use this JS:
`apex.theme.openRegion('your_region_id');`